# How To Use Objective-C Category of My Swift View Controller And Avoid Cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on swift project. I have a view controller named 'InitialScreenViewController.swift'. Now I want to use a category( not extension because I want to use already written objective-c category) of this view controller. I am facing an issue of cycle when i try to import swift header in category and categoryHeader in objc-bridging header.

Here is my category's header file code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SwiftProjectName-Swift.h"

@interface InitialScreenViewController (SwiftProjectName)<UIScrollViewDelegate> {

}

-(void)setScrollAndAnimations;

@end
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Edited Your Answer.

Comment: Which answer ? Have you posted an answer ?

Comment: Sorry edited your question.
Check the Bridging-Header Import line

Comment: Yes i was a typo. Thanks for correction.